# Akka unresolved dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am getting following error when i am trying to import dependencies :

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
```

This is how my build.sbt looks like

> name := "SBT"
>
> version := "1.0"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
>
> resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at
>   "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" %
>   "2.4-SNAPSHOT"

Please help me where am i going wrong ?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Just by copying and pasting this into empty `build.sbt` it worked fine and got the dependency, so this may be either proxy or network issue, if you use one. Also, the snapshots exist on that repo: http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.4-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be on the edge, why don't you use 2.4.1?
In my case it worked without resolvers.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.1"
```

Or you can use 2.4.0

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.0"
```

Comment: Have you "reload" the project? Please share the last stacktrace

Comment: [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.4.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
 at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
 at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
 at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
 at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)

Comment: Yeah i reloaded the project and i am not sure why it is still taking 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT even if i did mention 2.4.1 like  you suggested.

Comment: hmm... libraryDependencies are cumulitative. You might missed your previous settings somewhere. You can try to search for "2.4.0-SNAPSHOT" string in your directory. I don't know how this behaviour be fixed otherwise.